# how to remove white space in sql which in two words of same column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to remove white space in sql which in two words of same column.
Ex: My Table contain column name as EMP_name, In this column i have value 'State Maharashtra'. I want result like 'StateMaharashtra' at select from query
for matching names .

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update <<tableName>> set EMP_name = REPLACE(EMP_name,' ','')
```

Provide appropriate table name in "tableName"
This will update the value of column in all the rows.

If you want to only select the value but not to update the values then use select query as following.

```
SELECT REPLACE(EMP_name,' ','') FROM <<tableName>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which DB vendor you have, but you need a [string replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm#function_replace) function such as.

```
Select REPLACE(EMP_Name," ","")  from YourTable
```

This will replace a space " " with nothing "" in your column EMP_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Try the replace functionality:

```
REPLACE( string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string )

SELECT REPLACE( EMP_name, ' ', '' ) FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Description)), ' ', '') from TableName